# Integrating the function $ \frac{e^{ipz}}{(\cos z)^{a}} \frac{1}{z- \xi}$ on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

In a paper titled [*General Theorems in Contour Integration with Some Applications*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3sTxAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA378&lpg=PA378&dq=%22some%20integrals%20of%20circular%20functions%22&source=bl&ots=oUkHEpUurt&sig=ACfU3U3ff7CWTBNvR5LMik--bw-mkh43-g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlwJ735fvqAhUG2qwKHextAD0Q6AEwAXoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22some%20integrals%20of%20circular%20functions%22&f=false), G.H. Hardy states the following:

> Let us integrate
>
> $$ (i) \ \int \frac{e^{ipz}}{(\cos z)^{a}} \frac{\mathrm dz}{z- \xi} \, , $$
>
> $$ (ii) \ \int \frac{e^{ipz}}{(\sin z)^{a}} \frac{\mathrm dz}{z- \xi} \, , $$
>
> round contours $K'$. For the present we suppose $\xi$ not real, and $a <1 ,0 < p + a$; $a$ may be negative. We begin with $(i)$, taking that
> value of $(\cos z)^{a}$ which is real at the origin.
>
> As $z$ moves around any one of the points $ \left( n+\frac{1}{2} \right) \pi$, the subject of
> integration acquires a factor $e^{ ia \pi}$; and so the contribution
> of $\Xi$ is, in the limit,
>
> $$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \int^{(n+\frac{1}{2})\pi}_{(n-\frac{1}{2}) \pi} \frac{e^{i(na \pi + p x)} }{|\cos x |^{a}} \frac{\mathrm dx}{x-\xi} \, ,$$
>
> or
> $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{ipu}}{(\cos u)^{a}} \frac{e^{i n \pi(p+a)}}{u+n \pi - \xi} \, \mathrm du.$$

The contour $K'$ is a closed semicircle in the upper half-plane, and $\Xi$ is the part of the contour that lies just above the real axis.

Since $$ \frac{1}{(\cos z)^{a}} = \frac{e^{-ia \arg (\cos z)}}{|\cos z |^{a}} \, ,$$  Hardy seems to be saying that $\arg (\cos z) = - n \pi$ on $\Xi$ if $\Re(z) \in  \Big( \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi, \left(n+ \frac{1}{2} \right)\pi \Big)$.

How exactly is $\log (\cos z)$ being defined here?

Comment: I fixed the latex for $\pi$. Please check that I did not alter the meaning as well.

Comment: That was supposed to be a p. I was just copying it verbatim from the book and didn't change the ordering of p and i.

Comment: My apologies. $piz$ looked as if it might have been intended to be $\pi z$ or $\pi iz$. Now it does not look ambiguous.

Comment: $\log(\cos(z))$ can be well defined by integrating $\tan(z)$ as long as we don't circle the poles of $\tan(z)$. One domain would be $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x|\ge\pi/2\}$.

Comment: Your cut on the intervals will not work. As Daniel Fischer pointed out in a comment to my now modified answer, the residue of $\tan(z)$ is $-1$ at each pole. They will never cancel. The author seems to be using the branch cut I suggested in my previous comment and their results follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author seems to be using branch cuts along the real axis where $|x|\ge\pi/2$. With this branch cut, $\log(\cos(z))$ would be defined by integrating $-\tan(z)$ from $z=0$ (where $\log(\cos(0))=0$). Then 
$$
\cos(z)^a=e^{a\log(\cos(z))}
$$
As the point on $\Xi$ passes $\left(n+\tfrac12\right)\pi$, $\log(\cos(z))$ decreases by $\pi i$ (since $-\tan(z)$ has residue $1$ and the contour by passes in a clockwise semi-circle).

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Thus, along $\Xi$,
$$
\cos(z)^a=
\begin{array}{}
|\cos(z)|^ae^{-ian\pi}&\text{if }\mathrm{Re}(z)\in\left[\left(n-\tfrac12\right)\pi,\left(n+\tfrac12\right)\pi\right]
\end{array}
$$