# Fourier transform of $\Gamma \left (\frac{1}{2}-i \frac{p}{2 \pi} \right) /\sqrt{ \cosh(p/2)}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, gamma-function

Is it possible to compute the following Fourier transform analytically?
$$\psi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi}}\int \Gamma \left (\frac{1}{2}-i \frac{p}{2 \pi} \right) \frac{e^{i p x}}{\sqrt{ \cosh(p/2)}} dp $$

I am aware that 
$$ \Gamma \left (\frac{1}{2}-i \frac{p}{2 \pi} \right) \Gamma \left (\frac{1}{2}+i \frac{p}{2 \pi} \right)= \frac{\pi}{\cosh(p/2)}$$
and both sides of the identity have poles  only at $p=(\text{odd integer}) \times 2 \pi i$, but can not figure out how this can help with the integral.

Mathematica v10 returns the integral unevaluated, both with Integrate[] and InverseFourierTransform[].

The question comes from a research problem in quantum physics.

**Edit-3:** (makes Edit-1 obsolete).
The function is real-valued and positive, see continuous line on the numerically produced graph. Dashed lines are  $\sqrt{2} \, e^{-\pi x}/\sqrt{x}$ for $x \to +\infty$ and $20 \,  e^{+\pi x} \sqrt{-x}$ for $x \to -\infty$, confirming the asymptotics derived by @tired.

[image: graph of the function + asymptotics]

---

**Edit-2:** Here is what is relevant for the publication on the physics side. We are are proposing a method to generate quantum particles described by the wave-function $\psi(x)$. The unprecedented feature of the method (in the particular physics context) is that the Heisenberg product of coordinate-momentum uncertainty $\Delta x \, \Delta p \approx 0.537541$ is close to the so-called [Kennard bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) of $1/2$ (known to be satisfied by Gaussian wave-packet only).

For the momentum the result is neat:
$$(\Delta p)^2 = \int \frac{p^2}{4 \cosh^2(p/2)} dp= \frac{\pi^2}{3}$$

For the coordinate I need to compute $\Delta x \equiv \langle x^2 \rangle-\langle x \rangle^2$ where

$$ \langle x^n \rangle =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int x^n \,  |\psi(x)|^2 \, dx$$

Numerically I have $ \langle x \rangle \approx  -0.251022$ and $\langle x^2 \rangle \approx  0.150842$ which gives the above quoted uncertainty product.

So it would be very nice to find an analytic form for the first two moments of the probability distribution corresponding to $| \psi(x)|^2$ and also to prove analytically the exponential asymptotics (which distinguishes these wave-packets from other types known in the literature in my field of physics).

Comment: What type of problem doth this integral begin its journey in physics?

Comment: Have you tried Mathematica or something?

Comment: Shaping of on-demand electron wave-packets, here is an abstract I have presented on a conference few weeks ago: http://fqmt.fzu.cz/15/func/viewpdf.php?reg=650&num=1

Comment: @Alizter I am reasonably well-versed in Mathematica, Integrate and FourierTransform return the integral unevaluated.

Comment: @Slaviks OK that is good. Sometimes these kinds of expressions can be evaluated. I think it would be good to note in the question that CAS didn't return any results.

Comment: @Slaviks I do not think this can be evaluated. Should someone succeed please give me a sign, I would be glad to award a bounty to his answer.

Comment: I second @L.G. that there is possibly no closed. But on the other hand i think this integral is a great opportunity for practising asymptotic methods, so if you are interested in that, i will give it a shot.

Comment: @tired I would very much appreciate your effort! I have edited my post to explain more the motivation and  potential valuable results, even if they fall short of an explicit analytic formula for $\psi(x)$.

Comment: @Slaviks are you u sure about $\sim\exp[-\pi x]$. a first short calculation gave me  $\sim\frac{\exp[-\pi x]}{\sqrt{x}}$ which looks quite close in a logarithmic plot

Comment: @tired No, I am not sure! I was checking a single exponential. For positive $x$ your $\exp[ - \pi x]/\sqrt{x}$ fits much better (less than 0.1% difference for x>5). For negative $x$, adding $\sqrt{|x|}$ makes the agreement worse. Would you like me to update the plot?

Comment: @Slaviks
This would be very nice! I also checked only the case where $x>0$ so maybe there are some fine details in the case where $x<0$. I will write upe something as fast as i can!

Comment: @L.G. are the asymptotics sufficent for the bounty? ;-)

Comment: @tired Nope. The asymptotics of course deserves an upvote but is relatively straightforward to obtain. Finding explicit formula seems to be much more difficult. (+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, i will give a derivation of the leading order asymptotics for $x\rightarrow\infty$. For now, i also concentrate on the case where $x>0$, the opposite possibility should be doable with quite similiar techniques.

We start from the complex function given by @Leucippus.

$$
f(z,x)=\frac{e^{2ixz}}{\Gamma(\frac12+\frac{i}{\pi}z)\cosh^{3/2}(z)}
$$

We observe the following four facts:

1.) For $x>0$ the function is convergent for $|z|\rightarrow\infty$ so will close our contour of integration in the upper halpf plane.

2.) $f(x,z)$ has branch points at $z_n=\frac{i \pi}{2}+i n\pi$

3.) The corresponding singularities are integrable which may be checked by using the expansion of $\frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac12+\frac{i}{\pi}z)}$ near $z_n$

4.) The integral we are looking for is given by ($z=\sigma+i s$) 
$$
I(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\sigma f(\sigma,x)
$$

It follows that

$$
I(x)=-\oint_{C_{cut}}dzf(z,x)
$$

Here $\oint_{C_{cut}}$ denotes an integral around the branch cut which connects $z_0$ and $i\infty$ along the imaginary axis as @RandomVariable pointed out.

So far everything was exact, but now we need to start to make some approximations.

Let's write this integral a little bit more explicit.For more details how to correctly choose all the phase factors, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657668/integrating-int-fraceipz-cos-za-fracdzz-xi-on-the-complex/658340#658340) and noting that the integral around the small edge of the cut vanishs (due to the integrable singularity) we obtain:

$$
I(x)=-2i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(\frac{3}{2}\pi n)\int_{n\pi-\pi/2}^{n\pi+\pi/2}ds\frac{e^{-2sx}}{\Gamma(\frac12-\frac{s}{\pi})|\cos(s)|^{3/2}}
$$

It is clear that this integral is strongly dominated from the region of $s\in[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}+\epsilon]$ (everything else is strongly surpressed by the exponential) which means that only a small fraction the first part of the sum will be sufficent to get the leading order asymptotics.

$$
I(x)\sim2i\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi/2+\epsilon}ds\frac{e^{-2sx}}{\Gamma(\frac12-\frac{s}{\pi})|\cos(s)|^{3/2}}
$$

Using again the expansion of $\frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac12-\frac{x}{\pi})}$ (or asking mathematica) we therefore end up with

$$
I(x)\sim\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi/2+\epsilon}ds\frac{e^{-2sx}}{\sqrt{s-\frac{\pi}{2}}}
$$

Because of the exponential we only make an exponentially small error if we blow up our upper limit of integration to infinity so we are fine to calculate

$$
I(x)\sim\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{\pi/2}^{\infty}ds\frac{e^{-2sx}}{\sqrt{s-\frac{\pi}{2}}}
$$

This last integral can be done in closed form (it's not too difficult) and we end up with

> $$
> I(x)\sim\sqrt{2}\frac{e^{-\pi x}}{\sqrt{\pi x}}
> $$

Comparing with numerical calculation we find an error of just $0,8 \%$ for $x=5$ and $1,2\%$ for $x=3$ which seems incredibly good for me keeping in mind all the approximations we did on our journey!

Edit:

I think it's not too difficult to obtain corrections to this results by taken into account 1.) the second branch point 2.) more branch cuts. i also think that the corrections will be of order $\mathcal{O}(\frac{e^{-(2n+1)\pi x}}{\sqrt{x}})$

Edit2:

I corrected my answer using a correct choice of branches.

**Appendix**

Derivation of the last integral:

$$
\int_{\pi/2}^{\infty}ds\frac{e^{-2sx}}{\sqrt{s-\frac{\pi}{2}}}=e^{-\pi x}\int_{0}^{\infty}dy\frac{e^{-2xy}}{\sqrt{y}}=e^{-\pi x}\int_{0}^{\infty}dqe^{-2xq^2}=e^{-\pi x}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2 x}}
$$

Comment: I see what you did, excellent!! Simultaneously with your post, I have update the plot which confirms your asymptotics beautifully ($I(x)$ defined by @Leucippus equals $\psi(x)/\sqrt{\pi}$).

Comment: @Slaviks thanks , i recognized the $\sqrt{\pi}$ a little bit too late :) . But this was fun, thanks for the nice question!

Comment: I could be mistaken, but since $\log (\cosh)$ can be defined by integrating $\tanh z$ on the complex plane from the origin to $z$, I don't think $\frac{1}{\cosh^{3/2}(z)}$ (and thus $f(z,x)$) is well-defined if just the line segments between the branch points are omitted.

Comment: @RandomVariable your interpretation of the cuts is correct. i learned this technique some years ago from some very thrustworthy people and it worked in every case i tried. but i will rethink this part and give some additional information as soon as i can!

Comment: @RandomVariable i may be wrong, but is this not the same logic then in this answer? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657668/integrating-int-fraceipz-cos-za-fracdzz-xi-on-the-complex/658340#658340

Comment: In robjohn's answer, he has a branch cut on $[\frac{\pi}{2}, \infty)$ and a branch cut on $(-\infty, -\frac{\pi}{2}]$. The equivalent cuts here would be $[\frac{i \pi}{2}, i\infty)$ and $(-i\infty, -\frac{i \pi}{2}]$. But in your answer you appear to be circling around pairs of branch points.  And I don't think $f(z,x)$ remains well-defined if you do that.

Comment: @RandomVariable This does not spoil tired's asymptotics though (he's essentially taking only one branching point contribution at $i \pi$).

Comment: @RandomVariable i think you have a very valid argument here! Since i leave now for a barbecue, i will think about it tomorrow a little bit more tomorrow. it seems to me that the positivity of $\cosh(y)$ on $y \in (3i\pi/2, 5i\pi/2 )$ bugged me a little bit   because this doesn't imply that $\log(\cosh(y))$ is single valued there. Thank you very much for pointing that out!

Comment: @Slaviks yes indeed. but sorry for the confusion, i never thought carefully enough obout this stuff for my own.

Answer (score 2):

Given the two conditions listed in the proposed problem let $p = 2 z$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{\psi(x)}{\sqrt{\pi}} = \int_{\Gamma} \,  \frac{e^{2 i x \, z} \, dz}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{i \, z}{\pi}\right) \, \left(\cosh(z)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}. 
\end{align}
There is a branch cut due to the $(\cosh(z))^{3/2}$ term. The poles are determined by $\cosh(z_{n}) = 0$.
This lead to poles of the form
$$ z_{\text{poles}} = i \, \pi \, \left(m + \frac{1}{2}\right) \hspace{10mm} m \geq 0$$
From here it is a matter of finding the right contour to evaluate the integral and work around the branch cut(s) to find the integral's value.

Comment: Where does your second condition for the poles (with $z_m$) come from?

Comment: @Slaviks I removed the second condition. In general $\Gamma(z) = \infty$ for $z = 0, -1, -2, \cdots$. While typing I had inverted the values which led to an error.

Comment: Aha, and since the Gamma function is never zero, I can close the contour either in the upper or the lower half plane of $z$, depending on the sign of $x$, right? But then I think the poles are not in general limited to $m>0$

Comment: @Slaviks The branch cut will be the ultimate issue. For some examples of how to deal with branch cuts see Dean G. Duff's 2nd edition of 'Transform methods for solving partial differential equations'.

Comment: @Leucippus for what reason you believe the resulting sum has closed form?

Comment: @tired Do you propose a better method?

Comment: @tired I'd suspect it could be transformed to a different type of integral. I didn't state it had a closed form.

Comment: @Leucippus at least this approach is well suited for an asymptotic analysis of the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer to the second of the question (about the moments), using the ideas form @tired's answer and the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085313/). The first two moments evaluate to $$ \langle x \rangle =-\frac{1+\gamma}{ 2\pi}$$ and $$ \langle x^2 \rangle=\frac{1}{2 \pi^2} \left ( 1+ \gamma+ \frac{\gamma^2}{2}\right )+\frac{1}{16}$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler constant.